# C++ calculate gpa and standard deviation

Tags: c++, standards, average

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation and average of students in a txt file. I have the average down but I am having trouble using a function to calculate the standard deviation of the 5 grades. My prototype is 
void stats(double,double,double,double,double,double&ave,double&sd); 
I am stuck at this point. I don't know output my standard deviation or if i have my void function. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
float getValue(char);
void stats(double&grade1,double&grade2,double&grade3,double&grade4,double&grade5,double&ave,double&sd);

int main() {

    cout << "Name\t\tAverage\t\tDeviation\n";

    string name;
    int count;
    char grade;
    float ave,sum;
    ifstream input;
    input.open("data.txt");



          input >>name;
          while (name!="XXX") {
          cout<<name<<"\t"<<"\t";
          sum=count=0;
          input>>grade;

          while (grade!= 'X' ){
              sum+=getValue(grade); //sum = sum+grade
              count++;
             input>>grade;

          }
          if (count>0)ave=sum/count;
          else cout<<"no average";
          cout<< setprecision (2)<<fixed <<ave<<"\n";
          input>>name;



          }


return 0;
    }
float getValue(char x){
float ans=0;
        switch(x){
        case 'A': ans=4.0;break;
        case 'B': ans=3.0;break;
        case 'C': ans=2.0;break;
        case 'D': ans=1.0;break;
        }
        return ans;
        }
void stats(double&grade1,double&grade2,double&grade3,double&grade4,double&grade5,double&ave,double&sd)
{

    double var;
    var=(pow((grade1-ave),2)+pow((grade2-ave),2)+pow((grade3-ave),2)+pow((grade4-ave),2)+pow((grade5-ave),2))/5;
    sd=sqrt(var);

}
```

Comment: Just implement the simple equation - it is widely know and can be googled

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::vector`?  A vector would make the average and standard deviation easier to implement.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews no we have not done that yet.

Comment: You need to assign values to `sum` and `count`. Both are easy given what you have.

Comment: And you can't return a value from a function you declared to return `void`. (Either return the answer, or assign it to `sd` - not both.)

Comment: @AlanStokes do set both sum=0 count=0 then change to return sd;??

Answer (score 1):

Delete the line starting `#define`. It doesn't do what you think it does, and is causing your mysterious error message.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using the wrong formula for the standard deviation. Have a look at the [page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Basic_examples)!
The right order of the operations is:

1. Calculate the difference between the grade and the average
2. Square each of the differences that you have just calculated.

Now you have to tale the average of these numbers, therefore:

3. Sum all of them
4. Divide the sum by 5 (in this case, of course!)

This is your variance. And finally,

5. Take the square root of the variance.

Now you have the standard deviation.

What you are doing is different, because you have reverted step 2 and 3: first you are summing all the results, then your are squaring the sum. Unfortunately, it isn't the same, as (a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 which is obviously different from a^2 + b^2. This means that when you need to take the sum of some squares you can't take the square of the sum.

That said, you have some confusion in your code:

```
float sum, count,var;
ave=sum/count;
```

You don't need `sum` here, and `count` in this case is fixed (it's 5), so you don't need that either. And `ave` is passed as argument, so you don't have to declare it again (and neither to calculate it - if you are passing it as argument, you have already calculated it before calling the function!).

Comment: Ok i fixed my formula and removed sum and count. is everything else correct? Where would i cout<< my standard deviation? thanks!

Comment: Ok, now we have to deal with another problem: the function `stats` requires the 5 grades. Unfortunately you are not saving them, because in your `while (grade!= 'X' ){` loop you are doing this: `input>>grade;`, so you are overwriting the same variable every time. You said you can't use vectors, so I think you can't use arrays either. Then you can't use a loop. But are you at least sure that the grades are exactly 5, no more and no less? Why are you counting the grades? Is it possible they are not 5?